# Issue With Playing Video under BootStrap Modal

Tags: jquery

I have two issues with respect to my code

1.When i click on Video Buton for the first Time  it says 403 Forbidden (in the fiddle) and in my application its dislaying "its moved or 
deleted"

2. Is it possible to show a loader before playing a video, as its taking long to show a video

This is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickhere', function(event)
{
var videoSRC = $(this).attr('data-theVideo');
$('.frameclass').attr('src', videoSRC);
$('#videoModal').modal('show');
});
  $('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function()
{
        $('.frameclass').attr('src', '');
});
```

Could you please let me know hw to fix this .

http://jsfiddle.net/hLxauuaz/126/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickhere', function(event) {
  videoSRC = $(this).attr('data-theVideo');
  vid = document.getElementById("video");
  vid.src = videoSRC;
  vid.load();
  vid.oncanplay = function() {
    $('#videoProgress').hide();
  };
  $('#videoProgress').show();
  $('#videoModal').modal('show');
});
$('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  vid.src = '';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="videolisttable" cellspacing="2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="10%">Name</th>
      <th width="8%">File</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="portlettr" data-videoname="video4" id="tagnames34" data-stuff="" data-id="34">
      <td>video4</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default clickhere" data-toggle="modal" data-thevideo="https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/1c9ad9b71919e2c994/f3f680b44620be02/720.mp4">Video</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="portlettr" data-videoname="video2" id="tagnames32" data-stuff="" data-id="32">
      <td>video2</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default clickhere" data-toggle="modal" data-thevideo="https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/a09ad9b71919e2c228/91dd99df707480e5/240.mp4">Video</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="portlettr" data-videoname="video1" id="tagnames30" data-stuff="" data-id="30">
      <td>video1</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default clickhere" data-toggle="modal" data-thevideo="https://api-files.sproutvideo.com/file/e89ad9b71919e5cf60/46a1774aa09db957/240.mp4">Video</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
        <div id="videoProgress" class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;">
            <h1>Please wait while loading...</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <video id="video" controls autoplay style="width:100%; height:100%" class="embed-responsive-item frameclass" src=""></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope this will help you . Let me know if don't work.